# How educational is too educational?

Tags: discussion, scope, moderation, answers, deleted-answers

After almost six months being live, on 2023‑07‑28 [Pat W.](/u/480) deleted [my answer](https://law.StackExchange.com/a/88994/43335) (for reference repeated below).
It is in style a full legal opinion as to be handed in at the end of a typical 120-minute written exam at German law schools.
The closing comment reads:

> This would benefit from edits for relevance and concision.

This begs the question:
**How educational is *too* educational?**
Apparently submitting an answer that is acceptable in teaching at university (≈ education) is [*deletion-worthy* on this site](/help/deleted-answers) (which, may I remind you, claims to be [educational](/help/on-topic) in kind).

What irritates me the most, however, is the educational *uselessness* of the other (non-deleted) answers (which I presume were also reviewed with the same scrutiny as mine):

- My answer *cites the law*, § so-and-so Civil Code.
  The other [answers do not cite any section](/q/199).
  Their authors could have just as well *fabricated* their unsourced claims.
  *Failing* to cite the law (even though you could) even *deducts* points in exams.
- The other answers fail to name the problematic issues at hand:
  How to handle default in labor (here outside the CoViD‑19-pandemic context) and the *Lehre vom Betriebsrisiko*.
  Identifying and addressing controversial issues is the core subject of any legal question.
  You will not pass the bar in Germany simply by providing “correct” end results.
  In law school the *way toward* a solution is expected from you.
- My answer also showcases the internal structure (*Prüfungsschema*) of answering a legal question (concerning German civil law).
  Evidently things can nest pretty deep but that is how things are;
  it definitely aides *verifiability*, splitting a major problem into several “sub-questions”.
  Unfortunately it also inevitably causes a series of *intermediate result* sections, yet explicitly drawing conclusions is *de lege artis*.

It is therefore debatable whether the questioner (or other reader) will be able to answer similar questions *on his own* after having read exclusively the other answers (= the very nature of *educational* content).

---

1. **contractual obligations**
   Sajonji may have a contractual claim against employer E.

   1. **primary claims**
      Sajonji could have a contractual claim against employer E for payment of €3000 on 2023‑02‑01.
      (Taxes and social security contributions are ignored for the sake of simplicity.)

      1. **cause of claim**
         Sajonji and employer E concluded, §§ 145 ff. BGB, a contract of employment, §§ 611 ff. BGB, on 2022‑06‑24 obligating E to pay S €3000 after the end of each month, § 614 2 BGB, starting with July 2022.
         That means the most recent claim became payable on 2023‑02‑01, a date in the past.
         (Contracts usually deviate from and *supersede* this general rule of § 614 2 BGB. It’s quite possible payment can be effected within 15 days of each month if your contract says so.)
      2. **forfeiture of claim**
         The claim may have expired.

         1. **performance**
            The claim expires by fulfillment, § 362 Ⅰ BGB.
            For the months of July through December, E effected payment in full.
            The respective claims expired by means of fulfillment.

            For the month of January 2023, however, E transferred only €2950 into S’s checking account, i. e. €50 short of the owed amount.
            The employment contract does not stipulate that salary can be effected in installments.
            The fallback rule of § 266 BGB unmistakably does not grant the right of partial performance.
            If S does not accept the partial performance at hand, § 364 Ⅰ BGB, this claim has not expired.
         2. **setoff (hypothetical)**
            If S did not accept the partial performance, S will be obligated to return any unjust enrichment by the rules of §§ 812 ff. BGB.
            E did not put forward a claim for that as of today.
            If, however, E paid up the remaining amount today, he’ll be able to set off the claims by declaration, §§ 387 ff. BGB.
            The setoff amount is limited to the attachment of earnings cap, § 394 1 BGB → §§ 850 ff. ZPO.
         3. **intermediate result**
            The claim for payment of €3000 to be effected on 2023‑02‑01 still exists.
            Previous claims have been fulfilled, thus expired.
      3. **claim enforceable**
         The claim may be subject to inhibitory defenses *if* brought forward by the respective entitled party.

         1. **defense of non-performance of contract**
            E could have a right to retain his performance until complete performance of the other party (S) based on § 320 Ⅰ 1 BGB.
            For that E must have an enforceable contractual claim against S in a set of mutual obligations.

            1. **mutual obligations**
               An employment contract is characterized by rendering services at the exchange of salary, both principal obligations of this synallagmatic contract.
            2. **enforceable claim**
               E’s claim against S for rendering of services must be enforceable.
               It is enforceable if there is a cause of claim, the claim has not forfeited and S does not raise any defense.

               1. **cause of claim**
                  E’s claim stems from a. m. employment contract, which is not suffering from any defects.
               2. **forfeiture of claim**
                  However, the claim may have expired.

                  1. **performance**
                     The claim may have expired by virtue of performance, § 362 Ⅰ BGB.
                     The contract stipulates that S owes 37.5 hours of services per week, not necessarily uniformly distributed across business days.
                     In the first four calendar weeks of 2023, S met this goal.
                     Hence, the claim expired for those four weeks.

                     In the fifth week, however, E maintains that S has only worked 36 hours, a deficit of 1.5 hours.
                     Yet S claims this deficit was due to a power outage.
                     Indeed, on 2023‑01‑30 there was a power outage lasting about 2 hours.
                     S’s line of work requires electricity, so S could not render services as owed.
                     0.5 hours are attributed to a mandatory break.
                     Hence, the claim for performance of the remaining 1.5 hours has not expired by virtue of performance.
                  2. **impossibility**
                     Rendering services could have become impossible, thus the claim for performance of the remaining 1.5 hours of services may have expired, § 275 Ⅰ, 326 Ⅰ / 1 BGB.

                     1. **impossible**
                        In general, the employee must render services at the specified time.
                        On the one hand, working does not depend on time.
                        Operating a computer, as part of S’s obligations, can be done at a later point in time.
                        On the other hand, the employer needs to (*be able* to) realize profits from the employee’s services to subsequently pay his salary.
                        Thus performance at a later point in time will prevent the employer from earning enough profits to pay his employee.
                        Therefore, performance on a different date is inherently different than the originally scheduled date (*absolutes Fixgeschäft*).
                        Performance became impossible.
                     2. **unless obligee’s fault**
                        However, if the circumstance rendering performance impossible is primarily or overwhelmingly the obligee’s fault, his duty does not lapse, § 326 1 | 1 BGB.
                        Being responsible for the fault means being liable in the sense of §§ 276, 278 BGB.
                        That means gross negligence to the very least.
                        The power outage on 2023‑01‑30 affected an entire region, thus cannot be attributed to, for example, a lack of maintenance of the company building’s internal electrics.
                        E contracts a third party to supply the company with electric energy.
                        The used utility company seems to be generally reliable and reports show the outage was due to a snowstorm.
                        Hence there is no indication E deliberately or negligently caused the power outage preventing S’s performance.
                     3. **not obligee’s fault but in default of acceptance**
                        Since the employer does not bear the responsibility for said circumstance, § 326 Ⅱ 1 | 2 BGB may be applicable.
                        The employer’s obligation to pay the employee does not lapse if the circumstance the employer was not responsible for occurred at a time the employer was in default of acceptance, § 326 Ⅱ 1 | 2, 293 ff. BGB in conjunction with § 615 1 BGB.

                        1. **possibility to work**
                           In principle, it was possible for S to render services on 2023‑01‑30 during the power outage.
                        2. **no work**
                           S must have *completely* ceased to perform *any* work.
                           If S did the slightest amount of work, e. g. cleaning up workspace, this counts toward working time, because the employee gains, as minor as it might be, a benefit.
                        3. **offer**
                           S must have offered to E to render services, § 294 BGB.
                           An oral offer is sufficient, since E has to provide necessary plant and equipment to fulfill said performance, § 295 1 BGB.
                           On 2023‑01‑30 S asked the supervisor what to do.
                           This can be regarded as an oral offer to perform work, § 133, 157 BGB.
                           Hence an offer has been made.
                        4. **non-acceptance**
                           E must not have accepted the offer.
                           When the power outage occurred, S’s supervisor representing E gave S the option to leave or wait until energy is restored.
                           Thus there was a chance to accept the offered work, but E declined, i. e. did not accept the offer.
                        5. **production risk**
                           The default of acceptance must have occurred due to realization of a production risk, § 615 3 BGB.
                           A production risk is any risk that originates the employer’s sphere ([*Lehre vom Betriebsrisiko*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betriebsrisikolehre)).
                           In the present case providing electricity is the employer’s responsibility.
                           He must take account of the possibility of a power outage.
                           Since the power outage was underlying cause of the default of acceptance, E’s production risk materialized.
                        6. **intermediate result**
                           Albeit impossible to perform his duties, S remains entitled to remuneration because E was in default of acceptance when a production risk realized.
                     4. **intermediate result**
                        E’s claim to demand performance from S has expired on grounds of impossibility § 275 Ⅰ, 326 Ⅰ | 2 BGB in conjunction with § 615 1, 3 BGB.
                  3. **intermediate result**
                     E’s claim has lapsed.
               3. **intermediate result**
                  E does not have an enforceable claim.
            3. **intermediate result**
               The defense of non-performance of contract is not applicable.
         2. **result enforceable claim**
            S’s claim is enforceable.
      4. **result primary claims**
         Sajonji has a claim for payment of the outstanding €3000.
   2. **secondary claims**
      Secondary claims (e. g. damages) beside primary claims are possible.
      In particular, because E has no defense, it is possible that there is a claim for *statutory default interest* (currently 6.62% p. a. [with respect to your *pre-tax* income]), § 280 Ⅰ, Ⅱ, 286, 288 Ⅰ BGB.
   3. **result contractual obligations**
      Sajonji has a claim against E for payment of the outstanding €3000 (possibly plus interest) by virtue of the employment contract.
2. **tort**
   There could be a claim based on § 823 Ⅰ, Ⅱ BGB in conjunction with § 266a Ⅰ StGB.
   Your damage is the reduced amount forwarded, for instance, to the statutory retirement fund.
3. **unjust enrichment**
   Any possible enrichment is justified by a. m. contract, thus there are not any claims based on *unjust* enrichment.
4. **result**
   Sajonji has a claim against E for payment of €3000 plus interest because of employment contract.

---

PS:
There are other *similar* answers of mine.

- [online defamation](https://law.StackExchange.com/a/78159/43335)
- [defense against trespasser](https://law.StackExchange.com/a/78999/43335)
- [employer considerations](https://law.StackExchange.com/a/85641/43335) (not a full opinion)
- [default provider chargeback](https://law.StackExchange.com/a/76733/43335) (merely sketching a solution)

Maybe it is warranted to delete them, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Undeleted**

That said, most users don't grade or write issue spotters. We have variety of backgrounds on the site. Even experienced users (including the person who flagged it) had difficulty understanding where these facts came from, why they were relevant to the question, and how to read the issues. I'm not sure that makes it too educational, though

Comment: Yeah, I interpreted the closing comment as: “Contains too much information.” Hence my question “_too_ educational?” I presume my answer would not have been deleted (and now re-deleted) if it had been shorter and focused on a single issue (_1.5h are work time? Yes/no?_) and _ignored_ any other _legally_ completely _independent_ issues (_Get paid for those 1.5h nonetheless?_).

Comment: @KaiBurghardt That seems about right. In practice, issues with lower expected return tend to be omitted or mentioned quickly—e.g., at the end of a brief. Exam formats are often designed to ensure junior attorneys will notice potential issues that can later be prioritized with their colleagues' assistance.

Answer (score 5):

The form of this answer is highly non-standard for the following reasons:

- The facts that come out of nowhere.
- The highly nested structure makes it difficult to determine how the paragraphs relate to each other.
- It is unclear what proposition each citation to BGB is meant to support — normally, one would say what a statute requires and *then* apply it to the circumstances.
- You don't explain the law before diving into analysis (e.g. paragraphs
  1.1.3.2.2.2.3.1, 1.1.3.2.2.2.3.2, and 1.1.3.2.2.2.3.3 are not introduced as bearing any relation to paragraph 1.1.3.2.2.2.3).
- There is one section titled "enforceable claim" and another titled "claim enforceable" and another titled "result enforceable claim."
- It seems you have not exercised judgment about what issues are actually likely to be the primary issues in play. Being exhaustive actually can detract from usefulness. This form would not be useful to any reader I have ever produced content for — for a lay reader, colleague, professor, supervising lawyer, client, or a court — I expect all would have found this form incomprehensible.

Answer (score 5):

Just to echo other answers, and please take this in the spirit it is intended.

One thing I have noticed is that short, punchy posts often fair *far* better than more detailed, long ones - regardless of either's content.  I don't know the reason(s), but it is what is.

In my real-life world, the acronym ABC is valued:

- **A**ccurate
- **B**rief
- **C**lear

I don't know enough to comment on the accuracy of your answer under discussion, but it appears to me to be niether brief nor clear. To paraphrase Pat W. - it could do with some concision.

Finally, to add support to this little nugget:

> What irritates me the most, however, is the educational *uselessness* of the other (non-deleted) answers

You are not alone, not just in your particular example but others scattered throughout LawSE.  There are a number of answers that, although may offer a common sense / practical response and on occasion just pure guesses, they do not in my opinion meet the requirements for a [***good*** answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) but get upvoted and/or left open anyway.  Again,  I don't know the reason(s) but we're a diverse and varied crowd with our own particular thought processes (and idiosyncrasies).

I have, on occasion, downvoted and flagged such answers as low quality only to have my flags declined by moderators

I have since decided to ignore them as unavoidable noise and move on with my life.

Answer (score 4):

I have flagged your answer *again* and downvoted it.

Your answer is a spot on "Thema verfehlt" (missed the topic of the question), even for German grade school.

Your answer has no connection to the question. If it weren't for your writing style, based on contents alone it looks like you copied it from a totally different question that you keep referreing to, or an AI hallucinated something.

I double checked the question to make sure it wasn't edited and you maybe replied to an earlier edit. But it wasn't. As an answer to that question, your text made zero sense.

Maybe it would have. Maybe you are 100% correct about the laws behind it. But either *you make* that connection to the question asked *in your answer*, or my guess is it will be deleted again.

We are not in law school. On Stack Exchange, your **answer** will be compared to **how useful** it is in **answering the question**. And to me, it failed this bar spectacularly. I have no idea what you are talking about and how the facts that are not in the question came into your answer.

Take your "result":

> Sajonji has a claim against E for payment of €3000 plus interest because of employment contract.

What the heck? Who is "Sajonji"? Who is "E"? How come you know an absolute sum of 3000€ when no amount of money was ever mentioned in the question? This is as unhelpful as it may come. How does that help answering the OPs question?

More examples of "facts" you completely made up for your answer:

> Sajonji and employer E concluded [...] a contract of employment [...] on 2022‑06‑24 obligating E to pay S €3000

No, they did not. This is plain fiction, nowhere to be found in the question. You are just making this up.

Comment: Apparently we have a different understanding of the topic. In a _strict_ sense Sajonji (today the user name reads _user48892_) was asking _Do the 1.5h idling qualify as work time?_ The answer is: _No, it does not. The employer does not gain benefits from idling._ (My opinion rejects performance, 362 Ⅰ.) This strict reading of the question, however, has – and I’m paraphrasing your post – limited usefulness. S is not interested in a technical answer, but wants his (full) salary for the month. Inevitably you will need to extend the scope of the question so it addresses default of acceptance, too.

Comment: And sorry for _augmenting_ facts. It is necessary for writing a readable/complete opinion. We _know_ Sajonji concluded _some_ employment contract (in the past), and gets paid _some_ amount. The specific figures are of course irrelevant and made up. I could have just as well written “X euros” (literally the letter _X_), it makes no difference.
——
The letter E stands for _employer_. Right at the top there is “employer E.” It is standard practice to use the initial letter for unknown entities, e. g. _buyer B_, _landlord L_, _officer O_ and henceforth use _B_, _L_, or _O_ respectively.

Comment: Well, your answer would be better without the facts you *augmented*, because they are unneccessary. Because they just distract from the answer. Your answer is simply wrong. I think you meant to say that the employer owes the OP the payment for the hours worked, or in this case, ready and willing to work, but unable due to reasons only the employer could change. The employer does not owe the OP a month of salary, as you wrote. You don't even know if they worked the whole month. You are just posting a very misleading speculation of *augmented* facts.

Comment: If you cannot write an answeer *without* additional facts, at least point out that you made them up to better write an answer. At the start of the answer write something like "For the sake of the arguement and easier calculations here, I will assume you make 1000€ a month, obviously you need to adjust that to your actual salary". Leave out the date, it has nothing to do was anything. Your answer should be as generic as possible, to help not only *this* person, but a public reading SE.

Comment: Yes, the employer owes a _full payment_ of Sajonji’s salary: § 266 BGB says payment _in installments_ is not possible (unless the employment contract contains a clause saying otherwise). Have you even read my opinion? You seem to cherrypick issues. Nobody gets paid _exactly_ €3k/month. A mere _reality check_ will dismiss this. Yes, you _can_ augment facts in an opinion: You simply _presume there is no problem_ (→ do not create _extra_ content/headings/ _Prüfungspunkte_ in your opinion). That means we can presume Sajonji worked full-time the rest of the month (= no problem with rest of salary).

Comment: The point is: if your translation of a "legal opinion in the form law students would use" is so misleading, that it will be taken as completely wrong by a layman, it is not useful to this site. All your unmentioned presumtions and assumptions and augmentations do not help, they only hinder the OP in getting information.

Comment: By the way, since I am not a lawyer myself, I asked friends who are, because I was curious why it is acceptable to make things up in answers. The simple answer to my curiosity was: it isn't. It's not a thing. You don't just make facts up. Especially sums of money might change a case's dynamic, because it changes which court the case is brought to. You never make up a sum, just for the sake of it. Hallucinating, sorry "augmenting", facts into your answer is **not** something law students in Germany are supposed to do.

Comment: Aha! _The layman_ must be (still) able to understand a thing? Now we’re getting closer to my opening question (how educational is too educational). Could you point me to this Law.SE policy or is it something you made up? There are obviously many legal questions answering them in a short, precise and educational manner becomes too difficult to understand for the uninitiated nevertheless. — By _in style a full legal opinion as to be handed in […] at German law schools_ I meant _Gutachtenstil_ (AFAIK there is no common name describing this in English).

Comment: You’re mistaken. They may not admit it but law _students_ make presumptions all the time. Standard German law exam questions omit lots of facts: _P shoves V down the cliff. V dies. Criminal liability of P?_ Well, first you need to establish that German penal law applies. You will need to establish that P is ≥ 14 years old at the time of the crime. It is not even clear whether the drop from the cliff was lethal (high enough) or something else killed V. And so forth. Nonetheless you _can_ write an opinion _augmenting_ all those unsaid facts _and_ you get a good grade for it despite doing so.

Comment: "Need to establish" does not mean you just hallucinate a fact. You can make an assumption, clearly labeling it as assumption and progress with that assumption. That is fine. Just straight up making up facts and not labelling them as made up is not what you are supposed to do.

Comment: "Could you point me to this Law.SE policy or is it something you made up?" That the OP must be able to grasp your explanation, or it is unhelpful? That is SE basics, there is not specific Law.SE rule about this. It is basic human social interaction. Someone asks. You answer in a matter that answers their question. You could post a perfectly valid expert law analysis, if it's in latin, it's not helpful, because the OP cannot understand it. If you cannot explain it to a layman, it is not helpful to the average reader here.

Comment: I think you _really_ want to flag (nominate for deletion) several other answers of mine. I have _frequently_ (and sometimes even extensively) employed the device of supplementing facts _without emphasizing_ that these were not mentioned anywhere before. I think it is in _education’s nature_ that you “make up circumstances” to examine what the result would be, hence pointing out _this has not in fact happened_ is self-evident. – I’ve now [added footnotes](https://law.StackExchange.com/posts/88994/revisions) indicating (most if not all) presumptions. Is it now acceptable to you?

Comment: I seriously doubt this is a general SE principle. It would be surprising if [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) said: _Presume the questioner (or other reader) is dumb as a bag of hammers._ And in fact _many_ answers here do in fact _not explain_ things from scratch. – There is also a lower limit on how “accessible” answers may be: If answers are too easy (very understandable for layman) you may construe this as unauthorized practice of law. I mean there needs to be _some_ element of _teaching_ (e. g. in my opinion one heading contains the word _hypothetical_).

Comment: The footnotes for me moves it from "flag worthy" to "answer I personally find confusing". In other words, I would maybe downvote it, probably not, and not flag it for deletion. But please note that I am no moderator, I do not decide, I am only a single voice. That means others found it flag-worthy before, too, I cannot speak for them. I still think your answer would be way stronger if you just removed the fictious facts, since your answer doesn't need them. For example, neither the date, nor the sum matter. Removing them would be so much cleaner and easier than explaning them.